# laravel method POST showing no error message when submitted

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to submit my data, I receive a no error message and when I checked for the questions related to this problem, they said that it was the route method where I have to use POST instead of GET but I am already using POST function. What is the problem?

For the id part, I have checked that using dd and it is there but why am I still getting empty value for user_id when I view page source.

Relationship: personal_info hasOne checklist, using user_id as a FK

checklistController:

```
        public function checklist(Request $request){
                $checklist = new checklist;
                $personal_info = new personal_info;
                $checklist->check_nric = $request->input('check_nric');
                $checklist->remark_nric = $request->input('remark_nric');
                $id = $request->user_id;
                $id= personal_info::find($id);
                $id->checklists()->save($checklist);
            return redirect('/home');
        }
      public function getChecklist(Request $request,$id){
           //$data0 = personal_info::whereDoesntHave('checklists')->get();
        $data0 = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();
           if(count($data0)>0){
            return view('checklist1',compact('data0'));
        }else{
        return view('checklist1');
    }
    }

         public function showChecklist(){ 
$data = DB::table('personal_infos')->where('personal_infos.deleted_at', NULL)->get()->sortByDesc('created_at'); 

 if(count($data)>0){ 
 return view('checklist',compact('data')); 
 } 
 else{ 
 return view('checklist',compact('data')); 
 } 
 }
```

checklist1.blade.php

```
@foreach($data0 as $value)
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/checklist/'.$value->user_id) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
         <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$value->user_id}}">
         @endforeach
  <div class="row">
          <label class="col-md-2"><b>NRIC:</b></label>
           <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="radio" name="check_nric" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
     <input type="radio" name="check_nric" value="No"> No<br>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-2"><b>NRIC Remarks:</b></label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" name="remark_nric" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/checklist', 'checklistController@showChecklist');
Route::get('/user/showchecklist/{id}/checklist', 'checklistController@getChecklist');
Route::post('/checklist/{id}', 'checklistController@checklist');
```

This is what is shown in the browser:
[image]

dd($data0) looks like in checklist1.blade.php
[image]

Comment: Check your browser console, see what the HTTP status.

Comment: It return me this, http://evaluation.dev/checklist, it different I thought it should be checklist/id but it not

Comment: please post text here, I cannot access the link above.

Comment: I have added the screenshot inside my question

Comment: The link i thought it should be evaluation.dev/checklist/id as stated inside my checklist1.blade.php form part

Comment: from the img in your question, there is no id in your url.

Comment: Exactly and I have no idea why, when I click submit it just return me this when it suppose to show the id

Comment: You may inspect your html code from the browser, and log the id in your php code to check it why it's not there.

Comment: Could it be because there is no user_id inside the checklist1.blade.php?

Comment: You may inspect your html code from the browser, and log the id in your php code to check it

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by "log the id in your php code to check it". I did an inspect and it seems like the user_id value is empty

Comment: Check the order of defining routes
The rule of thumb is you should define most specific routes on top and generics once on t bottom.
Check whether you are  using the same path in file without parameters or resources

Comment: @SaadBhutto I have checked that there is no route with the same path, I have posted another route that is related to show the positioning that I have done

Comment: try replacing Route::post to Route::any

Comment: @Mark I tried using any for both the route and also in the checklist1.blade.php but it still shows that the user_id is missing

Comment: Could it be the fault in my controller where i try to pass the id?

Comment: @Dkna make sure $value->user_id  that has been called in your view (blade) has a valid value that you expect.

Comment: @Mark I tried doing dd($data0) in the controller and it did show me the id of the user but for some reason it is not passing through to the blade

Comment: @Dkna you may be triggering else block on your if else statement on your controller

Comment: @Mark I try removing the if else statement but it is still returning me the same thing, with the user_id blank

Comment: that's weird, why not refactor your controller and view and replace compact with array instead? then use the variable assigned by your controller

Comment: Erm sorry I don't know what you mean by that, maybe you could post the answer below and let me try if it works

Comment: `$data0` is return single value or multiple set of array value??

Comment: @RimonKhan I have added a screenshot inside the question for the dd part

Comment: show your `showChecklist` method

Comment: the showChecklist method doesn't really affect the question here but since you needed it I have added it into the question

Answer (score 0):

I guess your $data0  is no attribute that named "user_id";

I will do this :

```
 $data0 = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();

 // make sure count($data0) is a 'TRUE' result 
 dump(count($data0));

 // make sure $data0 "user_id" attribute is not empty
 dd($data0)
```

and if  you show this two results will make question to clear;
sorry for my poor English ,but I am relly want to help you.

**BTW** ,If you only have one piece of data, use  **->first()**  instead **->get()**
like this :
**PHP**

```
  $data0 = personal_info::where('id',$id)->first();

  if(!$data0){
     abort(404)
  }

  return view('checklist1',compact('data0'));
```

**blade**

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{url('/checklist/'.$data0->user_id) }}">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
 <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$data0->user_id}}">
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I tried doing the things you asked me and for the dump count it return me 1 which is a true result while dd(data0) return me all the information regarding the user which shows that it is not empty. The only problem now is I don't know why it is not passing to the checklist1.blade.php

Comment: Could you show the result of **dd($data0)** ?  and you can try dd($data0) in the blade like this {{dd($data0)}}

Comment: i used the things that you mention but the error remain the same, user_id still blank from the checklist1.blade.php

Comment: you can try dd($data0) in the blade like this {{dd($data0)}}

Comment: It just shows the user informtion in the checklist1.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have struggle with compact why not assign it as array since you just use the variable "$value" once in your template file.

**checklistController:**

```
public function checklist(Request $request) {
    $checklist = new checklist;
    $personal_info = new personal_info;
    $checklist->check_nric = $request->input('check_nric');
    $checklist->remark_nric = $request->input('remark_nric');
    $id = $request->user_id;
    $id= personal_info::find($id);
    $id->checklists()->save($checklist);
    return redirect('/home');
}

public function getChecklist(Request $request,$id) {
    //$data0 = personal_info::whereDoesntHave('checklists')->get();
    $data0 = personal_info::where('id', $id)->first();
    if (count($data0)>0) {
        return view('checklist1', ['user_id' => $data0->user_id]);
    } else {
        return view('checklist1');
    }
}
```

**checklist1.blade.php:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/checklist/'. $user_id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user_id }}">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-2"><b>NRIC:</b></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="radio" name="check_nric" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" name="check_nric" value="No"> No<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-2"><b>NRIC Remarks:</b></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="remark_nric" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It giving me this error,Property [user_id] does not exist on this collection instance., in the controller

Comment: sorry, im editting the answer I also found errors by my naked eyes while refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

After trying and playing around, it seems that by removing the foreach loop and changing the user_id to id, it solve the problem. I have no idea why, if possible could someone explain to me?

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/checklist/'.$data0->id) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
 <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$data0->id}}">
```

Comment: If you check your data collection, there is not "user_id" in attributes, so when you try this one "{{ url('/checklist/'.$value->user_id) }}" url is wrong but there is "id" attribute then when you try like this "{{ url('/checklist/'.$data0->id) }}" url is correct.

Comment: Ohh I see, I thought because I needed the user_id for checklist so I put user_id instead of id. Thank you for the explaination @CasperSL

Comment: if you want to id as user_id need to modify SQL statement.